# How to authorize request using Task based model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

We are designing application using MVC. We have thousands of user and more than 100 roles. Tasks (access rights for specific action )are assigned to roles. 
There are many tasks assigned to multiple roles meaning that task can be shared among roles. Due to nature of application we have to add/delete/update roles and therefore we can not use role based authorization.

Need help to advise on how to implement  task based authorization where application does not bother about roles.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bit flag enums](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) to create list of tasks and assign user permission using them. Unfortunately, even if you use ulong, this will limit you with maximum 64 options. Here is a sample code:

```
[Flags]
public enum TaskPermissions : ulong
{
    None = 0x0000,
    CanDoTask1 = 0x0001,
    CanDoTask2 = 0x0002,
    CanDoTask3 = 0x0004,
    CanDoTask4 = 0x0008,
    CanDoTask5 = 0x0010,
    // ... powers of 2
    CanDoEverything = 0xFFFF
}

public class Member
{
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public TaskPermissions Permissions { get; set; }
    // other things that are necessary

    public bool HasPermission(TaskPermissions permissions)
    {
        return (Permissions & permissions) == permissions;
    }
}
```

To set permissions:

```
var member=new Member():
member.Permissions= TaskPermissions.CanDoTask1 | TaskPermissions.CanDoTask2;
```

To check a permission:

```
member.HasPermission(TaskPermissions.CanDoTask1);
```

Sample AuthorizationRequiredAttribute for Mvc (assuming member is in session):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizationRequiredAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public TaskPermissions RequiredPermissions { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Controller.Session["Member"].HasPermission(RequiredPermissions))
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }
        throw new AuthenticationException("Access denied");
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[AuthorizationRequired(RequiredPermissions = TaskPermissions.CanDoTask1)]
public class TestController : Controller
{
    //methods
}
```

Comment: I think using flags is a bit limited. A regular enum backed by a hash set would allow many more privileges.